# Display HEX Value for color palette of images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colors, palette

Please refer to [www.granjacreativa.com/damepaleta](http://www.granjacreativa.com/damepaleta)
after you drag an image into the box, we show the dominant color as well as the color palette. How do I display the HEX value for each of the colors displayed?
I want to display them under the color box of each.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `functions`

```
var hexDigits = new Array
    ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

//Function to convert hex format to a rgb color

function rgb2hex(rgb) {
   rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
   return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

function hex(x) {
   return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
}
```

Read [Convert jQuery RGB output to Hex Color](http://wowmotty.blogspot.in/2009/06/convert-jquery-rgb-output-to-hex-color.html)

**Updated** From you `site source` you want to get `swatch background color` in `hex` then you should try after getting the `colors`,

```
alert(rgb2hex($('.swatch').css('background-color')));
```

to get all `swatch background-color` use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: Try it like `alert(rgb2hex($('#yourelement').css('background-color')));`

Comment: btw. function hex(x) { return ('0'+(+x||0).toString(16)).slice(-2); }

Comment: I apologize, but I am a complete newby therefore I dont know in which of my files I should add this code. I can share the complete code if that would be helpful? thank you all very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can get background color and display hex, here is a javascript snippet:

```
$('.swatch').on('click',
    function(){
        var context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
        context.strokeStyle = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
        alert(context.strokeStyle);
}).css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

We'll make use of canvas, since is simpler to get the actual hex color.